# Reversing a string and counting the number of characters that were reversed in C

Tags: c, string, reverse

My professor already got started on the code and it looks like...

```
#include "stdafx.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int numchar;

    char mystring[] = "This is the string to be printed  in reverse order";
    numchar = reverseString(mystring);

    puts("Reversed String is  ");
    puts(mystring);
}
int reverseString(char *mystring)
{

}
```

Now I'm supposed to finish it and that's where I'm stuck. I've looked up countless example programs of reversing strings but all of them were done differently and I'm lost on how to "convert" it into the appropriate context of the code that my professor has laid out for us. I'm also confused on what 'int argc' is supposed to be. However, I figured when it comes to counting and returning the number of characters reversed, I can simply put in something like this `for(int length=0; str[length]!='\0';length++);` but other than that, I'm stumped.

Comment: Your professor is asking you to introduce undefined behavior in your program. Time to find another professor? (UPD: no, that's may be not that bad. Did you miss `[]` or did you miss `*` near `char mystring`?)

Comment: `int argc` is the number of arguments passed to `main()` when your program was invoked. `char *argv[]` is the arguments themselves. FOr this question you can safely ignore both of them since you're not passing in the string to be reversed as a program argument, you're hard-coding it into the program.

Comment: So the instructor basically said "your assignment is to implement the function `reverseString()` ? Also, might he be a little vague about the "count", since by definition *every character* will be involved in a reversal unless the length is odd, in which case *one* will not be.

Comment: Think of it this way. Lay out a line of cards on the table in numerical order sorted *ascending* (1...10). Only allowed to pick up and *swap* two cards at a time, how would you reverse the order to be descending (10...1). Hint: Pick up 10 and 1, then 9 and 2, then 8 and 3, etc.). I can't tell you if each swap should count as one or two cards, since he was apparently vague in that definition.

Comment: technically a reversed string would start with a null terminator and therefore have a length of 0. So... return 0? ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried on just what the function reverseString() is going to return, you are going to reverse the entire string. So, if the length of the string is even, the function should return the `length` and if the length is odd, it should return `length-1`

Other than that, from your question, it is the usual string reverse function.

```
int reverseString(char *string) 
{
   int length, c;
   char *begin, *end, temp;

   length = string_length(string);

   begin = string;
   end = string;

   end += length - 1;    
   while(begin<end){
      temp = *end;
      *end = *begin;
      *begin = temp;

      begin++;
      end--;
   }
   if(length % 2 == 0) return length;
   else return length-1;
}

int string_length(char *pointer)
{
   int c = 0;

   while( *(pointer+c) != '\0' )
      c++;

   return c;
}
```

Comment: Since you already know the length of the string, there's no need to iterate over it again to determine the value of `end`: `end += length - 1`

Comment: Likewise, you can completely get rid of the call to `strlen()` by changing the 2nd loop to `while(begin < end)` and computing the length on the way.