# Writing a program in C with the function isAlphabetic to determine if a string strictly contains alphabetic letters or not

Tags: c

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   int  value;
   char c='Z';
   char alph[30]="there is a PROF 1 var orada";
   char freq[27];
   int i;

   // The function isAlphabetic will accept a string and test each character to 
   // verify if it is an alphabetic character ( A through Z , lowercase or uppercase)
   // if all characters are alphabetic characters then  the function returns 0.  
   // If a nonalphabetic character is found, it will return the index of the nonalpabetic
   // character. 

   value = isAlphabetic(alph);

   if (value == 0) 
       printf("\n The string is alphabetic");
   else 
       printf("Non alphabetic character is detected at position %d\n",value);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int isAlphabetic(char *myString) {
}
```

What I'm confused is how will I have the program scan through a string to detect exactly where a non alphabetic character is, if any? I'm guessing it'll first involve counting all the characters in a string first?

Comment: Why not just use the functions in `<ctype.h>` ? This is exactly their intended purpose, after all...

Comment: I think after solving your first assignment (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525527/reversing-a-string-and-counting-the-number-of-characters-that-were-reversed-in-c) you will be able to solve this on your own aswell.

Comment: What if the first character is non-alphanumeric? The index `0` is the index of the first character!

Comment: scan the whole string if any non alphabet found,done..what's so non trivial?

Answer (score 3):

Not going to provide the answer via code (as someone else did), but consider:

1. A string in C is nothing more than an array of characters and a null terminator.
2. You can iterate through each item in an array using [] (i.e., input[i]) to check its value against an ASCII table for example.
3. Your function can exit as soon as it finds one value that is not alphabetic.

There are certainly other ways to solve this problem, but my assumption is that at this level, your professor would be a bit suspicious if you started using a bunch of libraries / tools you haven't been taught.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take your questions one at a time:

> ...how will I have the program scan through a string...

"Scan through a string" means you skin the cat with a loop:

```
char xx[] = "ABC DEF 123 456";
int ii;

/* for, while, do while; pick your poison */
for (ii = 0; xx[ii] != '\0'; ++ii)
{
    /* Houston, we're scanning. */
}
```

> ...to detect...

"Detect" means you skin the cat with a comparison of some sort:

```
char a, b;
a == b; /* equality of two char's */
a >= b; /* greater-than-or-equal-to relationship of two char's */
a < b;  /* I'll bet you can guess what this does now */
```

> ...exactly where a non alphabetic character is...

Well by virtue of scanning you'll know "exactly where" due to your index.

Answer (score 0):

Scan from the first alphabet to the last alphabet.                                        Begin with a counter variable set to 0.
Each time you move to next character, do counter++;this will give you the index of non alphabet.
If you find any non-alphabet character,return counter there itself.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a hint :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char c = '1';
        printf("%d",c-48); //notice this
        return 0;
}
```

Output : 1

Should be more than enough to solve it on your own now :)

Comment: Maybe it's more elegant to write the calculation like `c - '0'` as this is more readable for the programmer